# R Shiny picking and storing favorites from checked dataTables

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

#### Background

I'm trying to create a multi-table Shiny app in which you can pick your favorite rows in each of several tables, through checkboxes. These should then be stored across sessions, and rendered in an additional "Favorites" table. Unfortunately my understanding of JavaScript appears too limited to achieve this.

#### Objectives

- Pick favorites by checking rows
- The value to store should be read from the checkbox `value` field
- Multiple tables should work independently of each other
- Picked favorites should be stored between sessions by writing to .Rds file or similar

#### What I've done so far

For a single table, the basic setup works well as described here: [RStudio Shiny list from checking rows in dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026740/rstudio-shiny-list-from-checking-rows-in-datatables/26109468#26109468)

In extending this to multiple tables, separated in different tabs, these do not seem to act independently. Example: If I select row 1 from table 1, and then row 2 from table 2 - the rendering for table 2 will show both row 1 and 2 as selected. If I now press the "Save 2" button, it will save three records: row 1 (table1) and row 1+2 (table2).

In table 3, I've managed to return the value of the checkbox (ID column no longer needs to be printed in actual table), but now I can only select one row.

**EDIT:**
The callback is now working, collecting the values of the checkboxes and working independently of each other. Still, saving is not working as expected. This is likely a Shiny/reactivity issue?

#### app.R

```
mymtcars1 = mtcars
mymtcars2 = mtcars
mymtcars3 = mtcars
mymtcars1$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)
mymtcars2$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)
mymtcars3$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rowSelect1 <- reactive({
      paste(sort(unique(input[["rows1"]])),sep=',')
    })
    rowSelect2 <- reactive({
      paste(sort(unique(input[["rows2"]])),sep=',')
    })
    rowSelect3 <- reactive({
      paste(sort(unique(input[["rows3"]])),sep=',')
    })
    observe({
      output$favorites_table1 <- renderText(rowSelect1())
      output$favorites_table2 <- renderText(rowSelect2())
      output$favorites_table3 <- renderText(rowSelect3())
    })
    output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
      mymtcars <- mymtcars1
      addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table1" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="op', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
      #Display table with checkbox buttons
      cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars)
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table1:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows1', $('#table1:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
  }")

  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable({
    mymtcars <- mymtcars2
    addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table2" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="val', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
    #Display table with checkbox buttons
    cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars)
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table2:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows2', $('#table2:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
    }")
  output$mytable3 = renderDataTable({
    mymtcars <- mymtcars3
    addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table3" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
    #Display table with checkbox buttons
    cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars[,-ncol(mymtcars)])
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table3:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows3', $('#table3:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
    }")
  favorites <- reactive({
    input$send_table1
    input$send_table2
    input$send_table3
    if(file.exists("favorites.Rds")) {
      old_favorites <- readRDS("favorites.Rds")
    } else {
      old_favorites <- data.frame()
    }
    isolate({
      new_favorites <- data.frame("Table"=character(0), "Key"=character(0))
      if(length(input$rows1>0)) new_favorites <- rbind(new_favorites, data.frame("Table"="Table1","Key"=input$rows1))
      if(length(input$rows2>0)) new_favorites <- rbind(new_favorites, data.frame("Table"="Table2","Key"=input$rows2))
      if(length(input$rows3>0)) new_favorites <- rbind(new_favorites, data.frame("Table"="Table3","Key"=input$rows3))
      if(nrow(new_favorites)>0){
        saveRDS(new_favorites, "favorites.Rds")
        new_favorites
      } else {
        old_favorites
      }
    })
  })
  output$favorites_table <- renderDataTable({
    validate(
      need(nrow(favorites())>0, paste0("No favorites stored"))
    )
    favorites()
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Examples of DataTables'),
    sidebarPanel(
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 1)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table1"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table1", "Save 1", class="btn-mini")
      ),
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 2)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table2"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table2", "Save 2", class="btn-mini")
      ),
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 3)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table3"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table3", "Save 3", class="btn-mini")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table1",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable1")
        ),
        tabPanel("Table2",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable2")
        ),
        tabPanel("Table3",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable3")
        ),
        tabPanel("Favorites",
                 dataTableOutput("favorites_table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is a working solution now - for anyone else interested.
It will read the value of the checkbox, and send it to the favorites table on click.

### app.R

```
mymtcars1 = mtcars
mymtcars2 = mtcars
mymtcars3 = mtcars
mymtcars1$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)
mymtcars2$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)
mymtcars3$id = 1:nrow(mtcars)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rowSelect1 <- reactive({
      if(!is.null(input[["rows1"]])) paste(sort(unique(input[["rows1"]])),sep=',')
    })
    rowSelect2 <- reactive({
      if(!is.null(input[["rows2"]])) paste(sort(unique(input[["rows2"]])),sep=',')
    })
    rowSelect3 <- reactive({
      if(!is.null(input[["rows3"]])) paste(sort(unique(input[["rows3"]])),sep=',')
    })
    output$favorites_table1 <- renderText(rowSelect1())
    output$favorites_table2 <- renderText(rowSelect2())
    output$favorites_table3 <- renderText(rowSelect3())

    output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
      mymtcars <- mymtcars1
      addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table1" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="op', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
      #Display table with checkbox buttons
      cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars)
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table1:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows1', $('#table1:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
  }")

  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable({
    mymtcars <- mymtcars2
    addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table2" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="val', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
    #Display table with checkbox buttons
    cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars)
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table2:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows2', $('#table2:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
    }")
  output$mytable3 = renderDataTable({
    mymtcars <- mymtcars3
    addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input id="table3" type="checkbox" name="row', mymtcars$id, '" value="', mymtcars$id, '">',"")
    #Display table with checkbox buttons
    cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, mymtcars[,-ncol(mymtcars)])
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25),
    escape = FALSE,
    callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('change.dt', '#table3:checkbox', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows3', $('#table3:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).get())
    }, 10); 
    });
    }")

  store_favorites <- function(rds="favorites.Rds", inputidx, name){
      if(file.exists(rds)) favorites <- readRDS(rds) else favorites <- data.frame("Table"=character(0), "Key"=character(0))
      if(length(input[[inputidx]])>0) {
        new_favorites <- unique(rbind(favorites, data.frame("Table"=name,"Key"=input[[inputidx]])))
        saveRDS(new_favorites, rds)
        new_favorites
      } else {
        favorites
      }
  }

  favorites1 <- reactive({
    input$send_table1
    isolate({store_favorites(inputidx="rows1", name="Table1")})
  })
  favorites2 <- reactive({
    input$send_table2
    isolate({store_favorites(inputidx="rows2", name="Table2")})
  })
  favorites3 <- reactive({
    input$send_table3
    isolate({store_favorites(inputidx="rows3", name="Table3")})
  })

  output$favorites_table <- renderDataTable({
    # Re-evaluate favorites each time one of the buttons are pressed
    input$send_table1
    input$send_table2
    input$send_table3
    isolate({
      #Unneccessary to bind the same table 3 times, then unique - but this works
      all_favs <- unique(rbind(favorites1(),favorites2(),favorites3()))
    })
    validate(
      need(nrow(all_favs)>0, paste0("No favorites stored"))
    )
    all_favs
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Examples of DataTables'),
    sidebarPanel(
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 1)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table1"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table1", "Save 1", class="btn-mini")
      ),
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 2)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table2"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table2", "Save 2", class="btn-mini")
      ),
      inputPanel(
        h5("Selected (table 3)"),br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("favorites_table3"),
        actionButton(inputId = "send_table3", "Save 3", class="btn-mini")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table1",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable1")
        ),
        tabPanel("Table2",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable2")
        ),
        tabPanel("Table3",
                 dataTableOutput("mytable3")
        ),
        tabPanel("Favorites",
                 dataTableOutput("favorites_table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```