# how to disable the checked checkbox of a datatable

Tags: r, checkbox, datatables, shiny

I created a table follow the example here:
[RStudio Shiny list from checking rows in dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026740/rstudio-shiny-list-from-checking-rows-in-datatables/26109468#26109468)

But I want it has other features: I want to have some rows of the data table are checked as default, and disable those pre-checked rows that the user can't uncheck them, they can check/uncheck other rows.

The checked rows information (including pre-checked and user-checked rows) will be used in later steps.

Anyone knows how to do this?