# How do I resize the row height of a DT::datatable in Shiny which includes a column of checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dt

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875435/5522197) answer, I've added a column of checkboxes to a datatable in Shiny. I can adjust the row heights with `DT::formatStyle()` when the checkbox column isn't present, but it doesn't work on a table that has checkboxes. Here's a minimum example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    column(width = 6,
           dataTableOutput("cars_table")),
    column(width = 6,
           dataTableOutput("cars_table_check"))),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    shinyInput <- function(FUN, id, num, ...) {
      inputs <- character(num)
      for (i in seq_len(num)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    output$cars_table <- renderDataTable({
      formatStyle(datatable(
        mtcars,
        selection = 'none', escape = F),
        0, target = "row", lineHeight = "50%")
    })
    
    output$cars_table_check <- renderDataTable({
      formatStyle(datatable(
        cbind(Pick = shinyInput(checkboxInput, "srows_", nrow(mtcars), value = NULL, width = 1), mtcars),
        options = list(drawCallback= JS('function(settings) {Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')),
        selection = 'none', escape = F),
        0, target = "row", lineHeight = "50%")
    })
  })
)
```

And the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `style` tag to your UI. Within this tag you can modify the underlying `CSS`. This is necessary for e.g. removing margins around the checkboxes (otherwise your `lineheight` does not have an effect).

```
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$style(
            HTML(
                "
            td > div.form-group > div.checkbox {
               margin:0px;
               bottom:10px;
            }

            td > div.form-group {
                position:absolute;
            }
            "
            )
        ),
...
```

[image]