# How to modify the following shiny code to obtain row indexes selected by checkbox?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, datatable, dt

I am interested to have a data table as following in my `shiny` app. After I select the rows using the check boxes, I would like to continue working on the selected data. The problem now is that I don't know how to get the index of the selected rows from this example. Can you please help?

I want to extend the following code which is given by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76748052/22180364) answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput("dtout")),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        shinyInput <- function(FUN, id, num, ...) {
            inputs <- character(num)
            for (i in seq_len(num)) {
                inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
            }
            inputs
        }
        
        output$dtout <- renderDataTable({
            datatable(
                cbind(
                    Pick = shinyInput(
                        checkboxInput,
                        "srows_",
                        nrow(mtcars),
                        value = NULL,
                        width = 1
                    ),
                    mtcars
                ),
                options = list(
                    drawCallback = JS(
                        'function(settings) {Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}'
                    )
                ),
                selection = 'none',
                escape = F
            )
        }, server = FALSE)
    }
))
```

I think it has to do with the `callback` function. But I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get the row indices where the checkbox is clicked, you can define a function which gets the value per `id` of the inputs

```
shinyValue = function(id, len) {
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) {
            NA
        }
        else {
            value
        }
    }))
}
```

and write these values into a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(isChecked = shinyValue('srows_', nrow(mtcars)))
```

Then you get a list of these indices by using

```
which(df$isChecked == TRUE)
```

See this minimal example below:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(verbatimTextOutput("idxSelectedRows"),
                dataTableOutput("dtout"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shinyInput <- function(FUN, id, num, ...) {
        inputs <- character(num)
        for (i in seq_len(num)) {
            inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
        }
        inputs
    }
    
    shinyValue = function(id, len) {
        unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
            value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
            if (is.null(value)) {
                NA
            }
            else {
                value
            }
        }))
    }
    
    output$idxSelectedRows <- renderPrint({
        df <- data.frame(isChecked = shinyValue('srows_', nrow(mtcars)))
        paste("Selected row indices: ",
              paste(which(df$isChecked == TRUE), collapse = ", "))
    })
    
    output$dtout <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(
            cbind(
                Pick = shinyInput(
                    checkboxInput,
                    "srows_",
                    nrow(mtcars),
                    value = NULL,
                    width = 1
                ),
                mtcars
            ),
            options = list(
                drawCallback = JS(
                    'function(settings) {Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}'
                )
            ),
            selection = 'none',
            escape = F
        ) 
    }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It worked very well, thank you very much! Also, I would like to do more when any of the checkboxes are checked using observeEvent, do you know what should I write as "input$"?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to have a condition which evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether at least one checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes, if any box is checked, I would like to update the checkbox input choices based on the selected rows. Sorry, don't know how to paste the code.

Comment: This didn't work properly. Sorry, new to this platform, not sure how to enter code block properly.
```
selectedidx <- reactive({shinyValue('srows_', nrow(master1()))})  
test <- reactive({paste0('srows_', selectedidx()[1])})  
  
  observeEvent(input[[test()]], {  
    
 newchoices <- reactive({c("None", unique(selected()$Organism)) %>% stri_remove_empty(., na_empty = TRUE)})
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session,
                                 inputId = "selectorg",
                                 choices = newchoices()
                                 )
  }
  )

Comment: In your comment you are missing backticks at the end. To the question: Use `observe` and the condition `if (any(df$isChecked, na.rm = TRUE))`. It will evaluate to `TRUE` if at least one box is checked, else `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please specify how to use observe? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `observe({ ... })` and put inside the call the condition and what shall happen then.